# Alternatives to Siemens Tc65 (GSM modem) as a terminal to process text messages

Tags: communication, gsm

I'm working on a solution to solve an existing inconvenience. Some "smart" containers send an alarm via text message when they're full. The number it sends to is a personal phone number from a worker in the company. The ideal would be to send some e-mails alarming the chosen people and maybe save the history on an local database.

To solve this, I thought I would use a GSM modem with a sim card connected to a computer or Raspberry via RS232-USB and program it using Java. When I was in the Uni I used the Siemens Tc65 on a very similar application, but I think that's kinda of old now and still a bit expensive. Which newer alternatives are there right now using 3G or 4G? I'm familiar with the SIMcom modules, I'm using the Sim800L on a different project, but they're a pain in the ass to work with and it's just a little board, I want something more reliable like the Tc65.

Also, is there a better/easier/more professional way to approach this?

Comment: Asking which GSM or successor module to purchase isn't really a question within the mission of stack exchange sites.  And that's doubly true when no criteria for differentiation are presented, though even with those the type of question would not be a fit here.

Comment: Just to clarify:  The "Smart Containers" are stuck using their SMS method?  So your asking for another way to receive SMS messages and create Emails to send out to a fixed list of recipients??  Why not just SMS direct to an EMail address? Most cellular SMS services allow for putting in an email address, rather than a phone number (at least here in the USA.)

Comment: Yes the Smart Containers are stuck with the SMS method. @ChrisStratton: I'm more asking like which modems nowadays are being used as terminals/gateways or if this approach is being used at all, since most modems I see are boards used for developing the IoT devices themselves.

Comment: Receiving SMS messages in an infrastructure setting is not usually done with a modem, but by buying SMS gateway service, ie, people text your number but you get the messages over the Internet.